# YAML multi-step deployment

Tags: yaml, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to be able to reuse the deployment variable on my bitbucket pipeline but this is not allowed. Is there any way to combine the steps?

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *build
  branches:
    master:
      - step: *build
      - step:
          <<: *deploy1
          name: Deployment 1
          deployment: Production
      - step:
          <<: *deploy2
          name: Deployment 2
          deployment: Production
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that bitbucket has this on the roadmap for [bb](https://www.atlassian.com/roadmap/cloud?selectedProduct=bitbucket) pipelines. I'm currently trying to do something similar. If I find a solution or something works for me. I'll post my solution.